# Can someone please guide me on how to reuse a function in a class?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Can someone please guide me on how to reuse a function in class in order to receive a different output with import random?

This is a blackjack game that I am writing in VS Code using python 3.7 with `Conda` base as an interpreter.

I am trying to reuse the function player_hand(random card) and get a different result for player_score(the card value as an integer)

and then add those 2 scores for a final_player (final score)
I would highly appreciate guidance and feedback on how to proceed on this challenge...

```py
import random

suit = {'Jack': 10, 'Queen': 10, 'King': 10, 'Ace': 11, 'Two': 2, 'Three': 3,
        'Four': 4, 'Five': 5, 'Six': 6, 'Seven': 7, 'Eight': 8, 'Nine': 9}
symb = ['Spade', 'Clubs', 'Heart', 'Diamonds']

player_hand = random.sample(suit.items(), 1) + random.sample(symb, 1)
dealer_hand = random.sample(suit.items(), 1) + random.sample(symb, 1)

player_score = player_hand[0][1]
dealer_score = dealer_hand[0][1]
final_player = player_score + player_score
final_dealer = dealer_score + dealer_score


class Bet:
    def __init__(self, player, bank=0):
        self.bank = bank
        self.player = player

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Player balance: ${self.bank}\n'

    def bet(self):

        self.amount = int(input('Place bet:'))

        if self.bank <= self.amount:
            return 'put more $ '

        else:
            self.bank -= self.amount
            return f'Player balance: ${self.bank}'


class Card:

    def __init__(self, suit, symb):
        self.suit = suit
        self.symb = symb

    def deal(self, player_hand, dealer_hand, dealer_score, player_score):
        while True:
            print('dealer', dealer_hand)
            print('dealer', dealer_score)

            print('player', player_hand)
            print('player', player_score)
            break


class Card2:

    def deal(self, player_hand, dealer_hand, dealer_score, player_score):
            while True:
                print('dealer', dealer_hand)
                print('dealer', dealer_score)

                print('player', player_hand)
                print('player', player_score)
                break

    def total_score(self):
        print(final_dealer)
        print(final_player)

    def winner(self):
        if final_dealer < final_player:
            return 'Player wins!'
        elif final_player < final_dealer:
            return 'dealer wins'


be = Bet('Player', bank=100)

print(be)
print(be.bet())
print('\n')

print(Card.deal('p', player_hand, dealer_hand, dealer_score, player_score))

print('\n')
print(Card2.winner('winner'))
```

Example of output below:

```
Player balance: $100
Place bet:5
Player balance: $95
dealer [('Queen', 10), 'Diamonds']
dealer 10
player [('Seven', 7), 'Heart']
player 7
None
dealer wins
```

Comment: `player_hand` and `player_score` are variables, not functions.

Comment: What's the point of a `while` loop that has no condition and breaks after the first iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the challenge here is in understanding how to use classes to model a problem, especially if you are coming to grips with object oriented programming (OOP) for your first time.

Your idea for what makes a `Card` object (i.e. something that has a **rank** and a **suit**) is a reasonable one. *But that is all a card should have.* All cards just have these two properties, and it makes little sense to create classes like `Card2`. The card is just a piece of paper, which should know nothing about the player or dealer who holds it, the other cards it is in a hand with, the player's money, etc. Including such extraneous data results in "coupling" where your player, bets, and cards all start depending on one another, leading to "spaghetti code."

Here is a quick implementation of drawing `Card` objects from a `Deck` that I wrote up:

```
import random

class Player:
    def __init__(self, money):
        self.money = money

    def bet(self, amount):
        self.money -= amount

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.build()

    def build(self):
        self.cards = []
        for rank in Card.ranks:
            for suit in Card.suits:
                card = Card(rank, suit)
                self.cards.append(card)

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def draw(self):
        if self.cards != []:
            card = self.cards.pop()
            return card
        else:
            raise IndexError("Cannot draw from empty deck")

class Card:
    ranks = {
        "Two": 2, "Three": 3, "Four": 4, "Five": 5, 
        "Six": 6, "Seven": 7, "Eight": 8, "Nine": 9,
        "Ten": 10, "Jack": 10, "Queen": 10, "King": 10,
        "Ace": 11,
    }
    suits = ["Spade", "Club", "Heart", "Diamond"]

    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def get_value(self):
        return Card.ranks[self.rank]

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} of {1}s".format(self.rank, self.suit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    deck = Deck()
    deck.shuffle()
    for i in range(100):#should error out once deck is empty
        card = deck.draw()
        print(i, str(card))
```

Note that once you write the individual pieces (such as shuffling the deck, and drawing a card) the code in your main function should be intuitive. Please let me know if any of the code does not make sense.

Comment: 'suit' is usually used to refer to the symbol on the card and 'rank ' to refer to the number.

Comment: Thanks, carried that over from OP's code without thinking it over. Editing now!

Comment: Thank you CodeSurgeon for the detailed explanation.                                                   I looked at your code and by changing the range to 2 I am able to print 2 different outputs of the card. If I print  print(Card.get_value(card)) we only get the value of one card                                            
0 Ace of Diamonds
1 Queen of Spades
10                                                                                             
Do I need to create another class of a Dealer and Score?
How do we assign the print(i, str(card)) to a dealer or a player?

Comment: I would recommend using card.get_value() instead of Card.get_value (card) as the latter is more verbose and makes the method look like a @classmethod instead. I would create Dealer and Player classes, but it makes little sense to create a score class since it would only store one value. As for passing the result of a print call, you cannot. I would pass around the card object instead. Perhaps the player class could have a property called "cards" that holds a list of card objects, and a method (e.g. called "take") that added a passed in Card object to this internal list.

Comment: Thank you! we just covered OOP in the course I am taking, I will implement your suggestions.